# In azure how to make api calls based on blob storage file content?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to preface this question by saying I am a beginner with Azure.

I would like to be able to upload an excel file into my blob storage where each row represents the parameters to pass into an api call. I want to then take the results of each api call and place them in the final column for each respective row in the excel file.

I tried to use data factory and I could not find a way to make the api call change based on the contents of a file, and I also couldn't write to an excel file. So, I decided to try Azure logic apps which would trigger based on a file being uploaded into blob storage, which would then trigger an azure function.

The issue I am having, is I do not know how to pass the row contents from the file in excel to the azure function so I can create the API call. I also am not entirely sure what the set up should look like, I have not used Azure functions before.

I am also open to entirely different approaches if using azure logic apps + functions is not ideal.

Comment: Actually, you can just use Azure function to do this, whcih programming language you are using? I'll provide you with a demo

Comment: @StanleyGong I am using python. I am also familiar with Java. Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python Azure function, just try the code below:

```
import logging
from os import remove
import azure.functions as func
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import requests


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob uri: {myblob.uri} bytes")

    temp_file_path = tempfile.gettempdir() + "\\temp.xlsx"
    #download .xlsx as a temp file 
    with open(temp_file_path,"w+b") as temp_blob:
        temp_blob.write(myblob.read())

    #read .xlsx and send request 
    dfs = pd.read_excel(temp_file_path,engine='openpyxl')
    for reqInfo in dfs.values:
        logging.info('request method:'+ reqInfo[0])
        logging.info('request URL:'+ reqInfo[1])
        response = requests.request(reqInfo[0],reqInfo[1])
        logging.info(response.status_code)

    #remove temp file after use
    remove(temp_file_path)
```

requirements.txt:

```
azure-functions
pandas 
openpyxl
requests
```

This is my demo .xlsx file content:

[image]

After I upload a file to a container that I specified in my function trigger, this is the result below :

[image]

So basically, you can use Azure function only to meet your requirement.

For more about Azure function blob trigger, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python).